# selected option value cannot be reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having two select boxes on my mvc razor view which are styled using selectBoxIt plugin

On changing #ddHour I want to reset #ddDay select(to set on first select choice)

```
var selectedDay = $('#ddDay option:nth-child(1)').val();
```

I tried with

```
$("#ddDay").selectBoxIt('refresh');
```

but it always returns same previously selected #ddDay option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `selectOption` to do that:

```
$("#ddDay").selectBoxIt().data("selectBox-selectBoxIt").selectOption('yourSelectBoxValue');
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `#ddDay` is a `select` element, you can reset its `selectedIndex` to 0:

```
$('#ddDay').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```